# c++ program won't compile

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#define maxn 200000
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class automat {
    vector<pair<int, char> > Q[maxn];
    int *validare;
    int *p;
    int init, st_fin, n, m, i, a, b;
    char c;
    public: automat(char*);
    // void operator +=(automat);
};

automat::automat(char *s) {
    ifstream f(s);
    f >> n >> m >> init >> st_fin;
    validare = new int[n];
    p = new int[n];
    for (i = 1; i <= st_fin; i++) {
        f >> p[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        f >> a >> b >> c;
        Q[a].push_back(make_pair(b, c));
    }
}

int main() {
    automat M("input.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

It won't compile. Can you help me and tell me why?
It gives me the message that cc1plus.exe stopped working, and I really don't know why. I am kind of new to OOP, so if you can help me I would really appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: When you ask questions like this please, please include the actual error. This helps people answer you and makes your question (and any answers) googleable.

Comment: What type of compiler are you using?  Is `cc1plus.exe` the name of your executable?

Comment: @Jacob: The error is that the compiler crashes.

Comment: @plast1K: No, that's the compiler.

Comment: Pre c++11 do not understand the ending `>>` in `vector<pair<int, char>>` properly.

Comment: Please include the actual error message that you're getting.  Aside from the reasons Jacob Parker gives, you'll be stuck at every error until you understand what those messages are telling you.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like that was an error introduced by an editor.

Comment: The code as above compiles & links cleanly for me on g++ 4.1.2

Answer (score 3):

`automat M;` attempts to call a constructor with no arguments (the default constructor). The compiler will only implicitly generate a default constructor for you if you haven't defined constructors of your own. However, you have defined one constructor for `automat` which takes a `char*` argument. You need to pass a `char*`. For example, you might want to do the following:

```
char filename[] = "file.txt";
automat M(filename);
```

This relies on array-to-pointer conversion to turn the `filename` array into a pointer to its first element.

---

The compiler is crashing because of a known problem with MinGW. The cause is that you're trying to allocate 200000 `std::vector`s on the stack. Most environments have a stack limit of about 1MB. You are easily going to have a stack overflow.

Comment: ok, I did what you said, but it changes nothing. It still gives me the same error, which is the one I stated in the first place. Won't compile and gives me the message that cc1plus.exe stopped working.

Comment: @AndreiStirb Can you compile _anything_? For example `int main() { return 0; }`? Just to make sure that the compiler isn't totally broken.

Comment: yes, I tried to compile other programs and it works

Comment: @AndreiStirb This appears to be a problem with MinGW. Apparently adding `'-Wl,--stack=0x2000000` to the LDFLAGS should help.

Comment: It perfectly compiles with changes proposed - http://liveworkspace.org/code/21Vidx$0. You can always check your code using online compilers.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: @Andrei Stirb - Of course you want to pass some meaningful string into constructor. But suggestions given by sftrabbit and 
juanchopanza explain and remove the error you get.

Comment: I guess the problem is with declaration of vector. Because if I change it to vector < pair <int,int> > Q[1000];  it works.

Comment: @AndreiStirb Oh, I hadn't notice. Yes, that's easily the problem. There is a limit to the size of the stack. You are allocating 200000 `std::vector`s on the stack. This will easily go over the limit. The limit is typically 1MB. Are you sure you need 200000 vectors?

Comment: @Andrei Stirb, even if the code is attempting to allocate 200000 vectors on the stack, this shouldn't cause the compiler to crash, but it'll likely cause a run-time failure in the compiled app. If this is crashing the compiler, you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

`automat` doesn't have a default constructor, so you cannot do this:

```
automat M;
```

Once you declare a constructor, the compiler no longer generates a default one for you. You have declared this one:

```
automat(char*);
```

so the compiler no longer synthesizes `automat();` You need to decide whether you need default construction, in which case you need to add a default constructor. If not, then instantiate the `automat` with a `char*`.

Comment: It does not solve problem, try to run program it will crash, at runtime.

Comment: @Saqlain It solves the problem that it doesn't compile, which is what you are asking about.

Comment: for me in visual studio it compiles perfectly fine as it is, but when i try to run it, it crashes, and i have shared reason above in the reply...

Comment: Ben Voigt also mentioned above in comment section, that he also see a crash, i think question description is little confusing, there is no compile time error, in the code provided

Comment: @Saqlain there was before you changed the code.

Comment: :) not me, perhaps the submitter might have changed it, i did not touched code

Comment: @Saqlain So sorry, I thought you were the submitter! I should pay more attention. It is likely that the array of vectors is too large for the stack. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the problem on my platform.

Comment: @ juanchopanza, no worries, btw this problem come easily on windows due to small stack size, as compared to Linux which got larger stack size

Answer (score 1):

Program specified above compiles successfully but it crashes at runtime and the crash is not due to default constructor not provided!

The crash when compiler tries to create

```
vector<pair<int, char> > Q[maxn];
```

And the reason is this huge maxn

Currently it is defined as

```
#define maxn 200000
```

And crash occurs while creating this huge vector on stack, change it to some smaller value i.e. 200 and you should not see any crash! Or otherwise you need to change stack size!

I was able to reproduce it on Visual Studio 10, in VS we can change stack size as specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(v=vs.71).aspx similarly we can also change for GCC http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt